# How to let stub to return instance on which it is called in case of using any_instance?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

For example, I have class A.

```
class A
end
```

And want in spec return instance of that class from stubbed method.

```
A.any_instance.stub(:my_method).and_return(<here is the same instance on which my_method is called should got>)
```

Is that possible to make something similar in RSpec?

Comment: `stub_chain` doesn't really fit me as I do not want to stub the second method I call later on the returned instance.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for you :

```
A.any_instance.stub(:my_method) do |*args|
    instance = RSpec::Mocks::space.send(:receivers).last
end
```

I dug this out from the rspec code here : [rspec github code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance/recorder.rb)

P.S. : This depends entirely on rspec implementation and may change in the future. The background is a little complex to explain here. I may add that in future.